# Implementing OAuth2 wit Swagger UI .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm tyring to configure OAuth with my .NET 6 app but am struggling

I'm firstly wondering what is the best OpenApiOAuthFlow for my use case where I don't want to register my app on an Identity Provider like Microsoft Identity, or Azure AD or Facebook?

If I need to, what website URL do I provide when my API is just in dev and staging?

I used random values for ClientID and ClientSecret - is there any way to retrieve these values without registering my app? And what is the ID that goes in the authorizationUrl and tokenUrl?

I used this site to help https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-oauth-2-authorization-using-azure-ad-and-swagger-in-net-5-0/

Here is my relevant code:

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
    {
        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
        {
            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/7493ef9e-db24-45d8-91b5-9c36018d6d52/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
            TokenUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/7493ef9e-db24-45d8-91b5-9c36018d6d52/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"Scope", "Reads the Weather forecast"}
            }
        }
    }
});

c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "oauth2"
            },
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            Name = "oauth2",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header
        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/1.0/swagger.json", "Weather Forecast API 1.0");
    //c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    c.OAuthClientId("ff11294f-2cc9-18d4-bdf6-6cf26670316a");
    //c.OAuthClientSecret("hXUedE-fItzZi8-7Mua4v9MxiTGx2--R_B");
    //c.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
});
```